# splitting the extract string in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got one way to extract string from this ["name space"]

```
      var  ca = "<%= doc["cas1"]%>"

       var newArr =  /&quot;(.*)&quot;/.exec(ca);
               alert(newArr[1]);
```

Got the exact text(**name space**) in alert, but the issue happens here, when i set that value in html,

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input type="text"  value='+ newArr[1] +' >');
```

it'll split into different like

```
<input id="textboxcast4" type="text" space="" value="name" name="Cast4">
```

so the users can only view the first part in text filed
how this happening?

Comment: can you please elaborate  more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround the value of the value attribute with quotes:

`newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input type="text"  value="'+ newArr[1] +'" >');`